# The long long type definition

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have only basic objective-c knowledge.

I saw a code snippet of an iOS project, which uses the following statement for a property:

```
@interface Store : NSObject
{
}
@property (nonatomic) long long amount; // 2 long type? why?
...
@end
```

Why is there a long long type definition?

What does it mean?

Comment: Its actually a remnant of C. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: Just FYI, it is not a specific Objective-C type, it comes from C (and since everything that is in C also is in Objective-C, you can find it in your iOS and OS X projects, even if you don't think you are coding in C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long long` (comes from C) is usually a 64 bit integer.